# C++ Get UTC date time of file creationdate

Tags: c++, time, time-t

Hey I'm having trouble coding the following:
I want to get the creationdate of a file by processid and I did it like so:

```
TCHAR Buffer[MAX_PATH];
if (GetModuleFileNameEx(Handle, 0, Buffer, MAX_PATH))
{
    std::string strx(Buffer);
    struct stat attrib;        
    stat(Buffer, &attrib); 
    std::wstring wsTmp(s.begin(), s.end());

    time_t creationdate = attrib.st_ctime; //outputs the localtime of the creationdate
}
```

this works great but however based on the timezone you live in the time changes. in utc+1 the creation time is like 12:00 and in utc+2 the creation time is 13:00.

I want to code it that the creationtime will always be utc so if you check it in utc+2 it will give me 11:00 instead of 13:00. and in utc-2 it also gives me 11:00 instead of 9:00.

Thanks for anyones help :)

Comment: Are you sure? I am pretty confident that timestamps of type `time_t`, for example returned by `stat`, is **always** in UTC. You might be confused that when _printing_ the `creationdate` the formatter applies the local time zone.

Comment: @prapin yes it displays the local creationtime of the file. if i change my timezone in the windows settings the time_t creationdate time changes too.

Comment: Please tell the `creationtime` as an *integer*, then check on an offline service like https://www.unixtimestamp.com . I am still sure your problem comes from a misunderstanding that the `time_t` is always UTC but possibly *displayed* in another time zone.